# Goのソースファイルに対してGNU GLOBAL(gtags)が使えない

Tags: go, vim

Goのソースコードが存在するディレクトリで`gtags`を実行し、タグファイルを生成しました。

タグファイル生成後にvimでgtags.vim(GNU GLOBALに同梱されたvimプラグイン)を使ってタグジャンプしてみるのですが Not Foundとなりうまくジャンプできません。
なぜでしょうか?

タグファイルの生成はエラーなど無く成功しているようです。

`global -xr`コマンドなども実行してみましたがなにも表示されませんでした。

ちなみにgtagsはデフォルトではGoに対応していないためpygmentsを使って解析をするようになっています。

環境:
Arch Linux
GNU GLOBAL 6.6.5

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました

ctagsのインストールを忘れており、
ctagsをインストールしたところうまく動くようになりました